# Standard errors for Composite Marginal Likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, standard-error, gradient, hessian, ordered-probit

I am estimating a multivariate ordered probit model using a composite marginal likelihood (CML) approach. In other words, I replace the full likelihood function by a surrogate likelihood constructed from pair-wise bivariate ordered probit models. The code is written in MATLAB and I use the solver **fmincon** to maximize my likelihood under constraints.
The code works perfectly and I recover the true parameters in my empirical exercise but I am struggling now to compute the standard errors.

My CML estimator is asymptotically normally distributed. The asymptotic variance-covariance matrix for the estimator is given by the inverse of the Godambe sandwich information matrix (Godambe, 1960) defined by:

\begin{align*}
V_\textrm{CML}(\theta)&= [H(\theta)]^{-1} J(\theta) [H(\theta)]^{-1} \quad \text{with} \\
 H(\theta)& = E \left[ -\frac{\partial^2  \log L_\textrm{CML}(\theta) }{\partial \theta ~ \partial \theta^\prime} \right] \\
 J(\theta) &= E \left[ \left( \frac{\partial \log L_\textrm{CML}(\theta) }{\partial \theta } \right)^{\prime} \left( \frac{\partial \log L_\textrm{CML}(\theta) }{\partial \theta } \right) \right]
\end{align*}

I tried to use $H $ the Hessian at the estimated parameter values and $J$ as the Gradient vector. Both are given by fmincon. When I then take the square root of the diagonal elements, I find very low standard errors which does not make sense to me.
Note that I am simulating the data.

Am I doing something wrong?